# Why transaction blocking simple insert in MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, innodb

## transaction Query

```
    mysqli_begin_transaction($conn);
    $sql = "UPDATE foldertable SET trashed = 1 WHERE serverToken = (SELECT serverToken from servertoken where userToken = ? limit 1) and 
    
    (folderId = ?
    or 
    RootFolderPath LIKE 
                CONCAT (
                    (SELECT RootFolderPath FROM foldertable WHERE serverToken = (SELECT serverToken from servertoken where userToken = ? ) AND folderid = ? limit 1)
                    ,'/'
                    , ?
                    ,'%'

                )
    )";
    $stmt =  mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sisii", $data["userToken"], $id, $data["userToken"], $id, $id);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        $serverError = true;
        return;
    }
    // echo "\n\n affected rows " . mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0) {
        sleep(15);
        // Insert into bin folder
        $sql = "INSERT INTO binfolder (serverToken , folderId) value ( (SELECT serverToken from servertoken where userToken = ? limit 1) , ?)";
        $stmt =  mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $data["userToken"], $id);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
            $serverError = true;
            return;
        }
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0) {
            $success = true;
            mysqli_commit($conn);
        }

    }
```

## Insert Query

```
INSERT INTO foldertable(serverToken) SELECT (123456)
```

## Problem

if execute the insert query  after transaction started but the insert does not have to wait for transaction complete . Because the update query on transaction does lock row involved with insert query.

## What I wanted

the Insert query will run immediately if it does not contain the same `serverToken` needed in Insert query.

Thank You in Advance.

[image: foldertable structure]

Comment: Not sure about your whole process, but why not moving your `commit` before the insert query?

Comment: If the insert failed ?

Comment: why does the insert would fail at all?  The issue is probably linked to the fact that the row to insert is linked to the one being locked. Thus you have no other choice than committing before the insert.

Comment: There is no other solution . If the insert query failed then I have to re update the whole updated statement ,then what's the benefit of transaction